# Unexpected termination of of c++ program

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

My error in the following program is: It terminates in the middle of execution and does not even allows user to enter the inputs.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    public:
    char city;
    int distance;
    Graph *next;
};

Graph **graph=new Graph*[20];
int size;

void create()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of cities:";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Enter "<<size<<" cities\n";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"City number "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>graph[i]->city;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    create();
    return 0;
}
```

The output statements do not even appear and the program terminates. Please can someone run this code and help me out. This issue has never occurred before and so I do not know how to solve this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Graph **graph=new Graph*[20];` allocates 20 pointers, but it does not point them to allocated `Graph` objects.

Comment: Do not use `using namespace std`. May not be the problem here but I can't compile it since `std::size` and `size` are ambiguous. There are other negatives to this so it is generally bad practice

Comment: Since you are using `cout` and `cin`, you should `#include <iostream>`.